# How do I maintain the order when splitting a string?

Tags: python, list, ordereddictionary

I am trying to create an ordered dictionary from a split string. How do I maintain the order of the split string? Sorry, my original example was confusing and contradicted the idea of an ordered dictionary. This is a different problem but I am not sure how to split the string as such.

My sample file "practice_split.txt" is as follows:

```
§1 text for chapter 1 §2 text for chapter 2 §3 text for chapter 3
```

I want my ordered dictionary to look like:

```
OrderedDict([('§1', 'text for chapter 1'), ('§2', 'text for chapter 2'), ('§3', 'text for chapter 3')])
```

instead of:

```
OrderedDict([('1 text for chapter 1 ', '\xc2\xa7'), ('\xc2\xa7', '3 text for chapter 3'), ('2 text for chapter 2 ', '\xc2\xa7')])
```

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*    
import codecs
import collections
import re

with codecs.open('practice_split.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as document:
    o_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

    for line in document:
        conv = line.encode('utf-8')
        a = re.split('(§)', conv)
        a = a[1:len(a)]     

        for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
            o_dict[a[i]] = a[i+1]
        print o_dict
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the last dict item different from the others?

Comment: This is totally unclear and an XY problem. What are you really trying to do? Your expected output is impossible because you're mapping the same key over and over and expecting the dict to hold all the values. That is not how dicts work.

Comment: You can never have your desired result `OrderedDict([('\xc2\xa7', 'text for chapter 1'), ('\xc2\xa7', 'text for chapter 2'), ('\xc2\xa7', 'text for chapter 3')])`, since the key for all the dictionary entries is the same, which is impossible.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye sorry fixed that, thanks!

Comment: Other than that, you mean to be iterating through the list two entries at a time, instead of one at a time, as pointed out in multiple answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of your code your loop is incorrect.  You want the first `§` with the first text entry. You also want to skip the `§` elements as a key to your dictionary, therefore you need a step of 2 for the loop. Finally, you may want to strip spaces off the start/end of the text.

```
for i in range(1, len(a), 2):
    o_dict["{}{}".format(a[i - 1], i / 2 + 1)] = a[i].strip()
print o_dict 

for k, v in o_dict.iteritems():
    print k.decode('utf-8'), v
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('\xc2\xa71', 'text for chapter 1'), ('\xc2\xa72', 'text for chapter 2'), ('\xc2\xa73', 'text for chapter 3')])

§1 text for chapter 1
§2 text for chapter 2
§3 text for chapter 3
```

Edit: I changed my code to reflect the edits to OPs question.

Comment: Probably correct, but really bizarre. Why are we creating an ordered dict that maps every single chapter's text to the § symbol? That makes zero sense.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Perhaps OP wants to split on multiple characters later or something.

Comment: I am just using a sample text file right now. Eventually the script should split text files based on sections, and the sections will be labeled as §1, §2, §3, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering both questions!

Comment: @Shivani:  Note that you will have issues with ordering if your section number goes above 10.  It may be better to use a tuple as they key ie. `o_dict[(a[i - 1], i / 2 + 1)] = a[i].strip()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the OrderedDict, it's with your `for` loop.  Your loop does the following:

points ' text for chapter 1 ' to '\xc2\xa7' # in the dict as is

points '\xc2\xa7' to ' text for chapter 2 ' # this gets overwritten

points ' text for chapter 2 ' to '\xc2\xa7' # in the dict as is

points '\xc2\xa7' to ' text for chapter 3 ' # this overwrites the 2nd entry, so it ends up in the second place

Not sure what you actually want your dict to contain, or I'd suggest some code....

Comment: Thanks, it needed to be range(1, (end value), 2). Still not sure about the right end value but thanks for the tip.